# program showing olympic games or soccer world championship. error message

Tags: python

"im fairly new to python. I want to create a program that shows the olympic games or soccer World Championship but i keep getting an error message at the first print function and i don't know what i am doing wrong here."

```
year = int(input("a year between 1950 and 2050: "))
if year < 1950:
print("follow instructions")

elif (year%4) == 0:
   print("{0} olypic games".format(num))

elif (year%2) == 0:
   print("{0} soccer World Championship ")

else:
   print("{0} nothing special this year".format(num))
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that your forgot to indent the first call to `print`:

```py
year = int(input("a year between 1950 and 2050: "))
if year < 1950:
   # I indented here
   print("follow instructions")

elif (year%4) == 0:
   print("{0} olypic games".format(num))

elif (year%2) == 0:
   print("{0} soccer World Championship ")

else:
   print("{0} nothing special this year".format(num))
```

Note that you also forget to call the `format` method in the case `year % 2 == 0`:

```py
elif (year%2) == 0:
   # I added .format(num)
   print("{0} soccer World Championship ".format(num))
```

By the way, please remember to put the Error stack trace when you're asking for help next time, it is easier to help you then!

Answer (score 1):

make sure it is correctly idented:

```
year = int(input("a year between 1950 and 2050: "))
if year < 1950:
   print("follow instructions")

elif year%4 == 0:
   print("{0} olypic games".format(num))

elif year%2 == 0:
   print("{0} soccer World Championship".format(num))

else:
   print("{0} nothing special this year".format(num))
```